# Adding algebraic X notation

Tags: c#

I am trying for the last few hours on how to parse a string with algebric notation.

For example if I have the input:

```
X+8X-21X+21X+16
```

The output should be:

```
9X+16
```

so far if I tried to see if there exists a number behind X and tried many cases, however I keep on getting an index out of bounds error, and rightufully so. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
int getXPosition= LHSString.IndexOf("X");
int noOfXs = LHSString.Split('X').Length - 1;
int XCount = 0;

if (getXPosition > -1)
{
    while (XCount <= noOfXs)
    {
        int posX = getPositionX(s);
        Regex noBeforeX = new Regex(@"\d+");
        if ((posX - 1) > -1 && noBeforeX.IsMatch(LHSString.Substring(posX-1,1)))
        {
            string getNumber = LHSString.Substring(posX-1, 1);
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(getNumber);
        }
        if ((posX - 2) > -1 && noBeforeX.IsMatch(LHSString.Substring(posX - 2, 1)))
        {
            string gotNumber = LHSString.Substring(posX - 1, 1);
            int Number=Convert.ToInt32(gotNumber);
            sum += Number;
        }

        XCount++;

        s = s.Substring(posX + 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: can i assume that your input are always correct and the operator is only `+` and `-`?

Comment: @david It can be * and /,and yes always correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a more maintainable approach. 
separate different code parts and use collection of class that will represent the "part" in the algebraic equation. 
here is my suggestion:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] operators = { "+", "-", "/", "*" };
        string test = "X+8X-21X+21X+16";
        int locationcounter = 0;
        string part = string.Empty;
        List<Part> partsList = new List<Part>();

        for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
        {
            if (operators.Contains(test[i].ToString()))
            {
                var operatorbeofore = (partsList.Count <= 0 ? "" : partsList[partsList.Count - 1].OperatorAfter);
                partsList.Add(new Part(part, operatorbeofore, test[i].ToString(), locationcounter));
                locationcounter++;
                part = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                part += test[i].ToString();
            }
        }

        // last part that remain
        if (part != string.Empty)
        {
            partsList.Add(new Part(part, partsList[partsList.Count() - 1].OperatorAfter, "", locationcounter++));
        }
        // output
        Console.WriteLine(GetResultOutput(partsList));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GetResultOutput(List<Part> algebraicexpression)
    {
        // reduce all vars
        var vars = algebraicexpression.Where(x => x.IsVar).OrderBy(x => x.locationInEqution).ToList();
        int lastVarResult = 0;
        int varResult = 0;
        if (vars.Count() > 1)
        {
            lastVarResult = GetCalculation(vars[0].Value, vars[1].Value, vars[1].OperatorBefore);
            for (int i = 2; i < vars.Count(); i++)
            {
                varResult = GetCalculation(lastVarResult, vars[i].Value, vars[i].OperatorBefore);
                lastVarResult = varResult;
            }
        }
        else if (vars.Count() == 1)
        {
            lastVarResult = vars[0].Value;
        }
        // calculate all "free" numbers
        var numbers = algebraicexpression.Where(x => x.IsVar == false).OrderBy(x => x.locationInEqution).ToList();
        int lastResult = 0;
        int Result = 0;
        if (numbers.Count() > 1)
        {
            lastResult = GetCalculation(vars[0].Value, vars[1].Value, vars[1].OperatorBefore);
            for (int i = 2; i < vars.Count(); i++)
            {
                Result = GetCalculation(lastResult, vars[i].Value, vars[i].OperatorBefore);
                lastResult = varResult;
            }
        }
        else if (numbers.Count() == 1)
        {
            Result = numbers[0].Value;
        }

        string stringresult = string.Empty;
        if (varResult != 0)
        {
            stringresult = varResult.ToString() + vars[0].Notation;
        }

        if (Result > 0)
        {
            stringresult = stringresult + "+" + Result.ToString();
        }
        else if (Result < 0)
        {
            stringresult = stringresult + "-" + Result.ToString();
        }

        return stringresult;
    }

    private static int GetCalculation(int x, int y, string eqoperator)
    {
        if (eqoperator == "+")
        {
            return x + y;
        }
        else if (eqoperator == "-")
        {
            return x - y;
        }
        else if (eqoperator == "*")
        {
            return x * y;
        }
        else if (eqoperator == "/")
        {
            return x / y;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}

class Part
{
    public string MyAlgebricPart;
    public string OperatorBefore;
    public string OperatorAfter;
    public int locationInEqution;

    public Part(string part, string operatorbefore, string operatorafter, int location)
    {
        this.MyAlgebricPart = part;
        this.OperatorAfter = operatorafter;
        this.OperatorBefore = operatorbefore;
        this.locationInEqution = location;
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (MyAlgebricPart.Count() == 1 && Notation != string.Empty)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                string result = new String(MyAlgebricPart.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
                return Convert.ToInt32(result);
            }
        }
    }
    public string Notation
    {
        get
        {
            var onlyLetters = new String(MyAlgebricPart.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
            if (onlyLetters != "")
            {
                return onlyLetters[0].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

        }
    }

    public bool IsVar
    {
        get
        {
            if (Notation == string.Empty)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot!. Means so much you worked hard on it